# Synonymize [charles] and [charles-proxy]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[charles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/charles) (330 questions) and [charles-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/charles-proxy) (48 questions) both unambiguously refer to the same proxy.

Only [charles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/charles) has a tag wiki excerpt, which is clearly about the proxy:

> Charles is an HTTP proxy / HTTP monitor / Reverse Proxy that enables a developer to view all of the HTTP and SSL / HTTPS traffic between their machine and the Internet. This includes requests, responses and the HTTP headers.

Can we synonymize them?

Comment: So `charles` should proxy `charles-proxy`?

Comment: I would synonym [charles] to [charles-proxy] in this case, since the latter is less ambiguous

Comment: Title suggestion: "[charles] proxy [charles-proxy]"